# How to delta deploy packages using Sitecore Serialization?

Tags: tds, serialization

Is there a recommended way to delta build Sitecore items package using Sitecore Content Serialization (SCS) as we used to do in TDS? It seems this feature is missed to be inherited from TDS into SCS. Building a package with all Sitecore items is time consuming and impacts our build time. Are there any best practices around it that the Sitecore community is following?

We have workarounds to achieve the same. For e.g. one way this can be done is by including only the projects with changed items in below command but this still includes all the unchanged items of the included projects too.

```
dotnet sitecore ser pkg create -i MyProject1, MyProject2,... MyProjectN
```

Also, this workaround requires us to add the project names manually while building the package and we would want to prevent any manual step to perform this.

Appreciate any suggestions in advance!

Comment: How many items and how much time?

Comment: There are approx 8000 total nodes prefetched by build command each time including master and core db items. It may take approx 5-20 minutes to build the package, mostly on the lower side of it but we wanted to bring it down to <1 minute.

Comment: How do you have 8000 items in serialization? :O - This seems like an issue with the setup.

Comment: I understand your concern Richard. We have lots of stuff going in the solution matured over 8 years with 100s of renderings, templates, dictionary items with approx 100 languages supported and then the scripts, customizations in shell. That is the reason for my ask if anyone has found a way to have delta deploy work in SCS.